# Fast moving parts of file (like zero-copy on FS level)

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, ext4, hfs+

The problem:
I need to cut large wave file.

I feel there should be a way (or its possible to create it) to move some part of a file into a separate one almost without copying. That is all filesystems use clusters and have maps/lists to point which clusters belong to which files. The operation would be to specify that some clusters point to a new file + handling of tails.

But I haven't heard about similar APIs.
Do they exist ?

Adding filesystem specific tags to attract people working on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, there's no published code to do that. It might be available soon though:https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/3/31/543